# Transfer files to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-blob-storage

I'am looking for.. what is the best option to trasnfer files from my VM's (Onpremises) to Azure Blob Storage and if this option can be automate.

I'am a new Azure's user, I'am starting to learn about Azure.

Thank you!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: One option is to use Azure data factory to copy files from VM to blob storage.

Comment: Hello, this option works for VMs backups?

Comment: Check in ADF with File system connector

Answer (score 0):

> I'am looking for.. what is the best option to trasnfer files from my VM's (Onpremises) to Azure Blob Storage and if this option can be automate.

To transfer files from an **on-premises** location to an **Azure Storage account**, you can execute the PowerShell script using **Task Scheduler** by following the steps.

1. [Create a Storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-create?tabs=azure-portal) with **blob anonymous** enabled.

[image]

2. Enable connections from all networks to the on-premises network.

[image]

3. Create a new container in your storage account and modify the container's access policy to enable anonymous access.

[image]

4. Navigate to the container and generate the **SAS token** with the necessary permissions, then copy the blob `SAS URL`.

[image]

```
"C:\Venkat\Azure_AD" : Local Path
```

5. Here is the script to copy files from an `on-premises` location to an `Azure Storage account`.

```
 azcopy cp "C:\Venkat\Azure_AD"  "https://venkatstoragetest.blob.core.windows.net/venkat?sp=racwdli&st=2024-03-25T06:36:57Z&se=2024-03-25T14:36:57Z&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=DElfhf6x7YRdabM5SahaS%2BvD1qW0L%2FcVSGIJDJxo8fk%3D"  --recursive
```

6. To automate file copying to an Azure Storage account, you can utilize the **Task Scheduler** on an on-premises machine. For configuration , refer to the [link](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/07/03/how-to-automate-powershell-scripts-with-task-scheduler/)  by **Jeff Melnick** on setting up the **Task Scheduler**.

**Output:**

[image]

After executing the script, the folder was successfully transferred from the **on-premises**  to **Azure Blob Storage**.

[image]